# My Windows 10 version 1511 won't update to latest 1803?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I had installed a Windows 10 64-bit version 1511 on my laptop.  After completing the necessary steps, it started downloading updates. After some time I could see that 40GB in my Windows drive was full and so many updates were installed.

But there was this update "Windows feature update 1803", it was downloading. The problem is that it has been three days that my system downloads this update, try to install it, but then start downloading again and start installing again. It hasn't been able to completely update my windows version and this update still shows, sometimes downloading, and sometimes installing, but can do nothing else. I have given it fixed 2MB Internet, and I keep it running until it restarts itself.

Please, help.. is there anything I am missing here, or there is something else that I need to. I want to update my windows to the latest version.

**Note:** my windows (1511) is authentic, activated, though I got that window 2 or 3 years ago.

Comment: Your likely running into several issues, best way to upgrade to 1809 is to use the [upgrade assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3159635/windows-10-update-assistant).  However, updates after 1607, made a hardware requirement change.  Knowing what your CPU is would be helpful to determine if your hardware is compatible with 1809.  If you want 1803, you will need to create your own installation media but start the installation from within Windows.  Please edit your question to provide the necessary information about your hardware to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But there was this update "Windows feature update 1803", it was downloading. The problem is that it has been three days that my system downloads this update, try to install it, but then start downloading again and start installing again. It hasn't been able to completely update my windows version and this update still shows, sometimes downloading, and sometimes installing, but can do nothing else. I have given it fixed 2MB Internet, and I keep it running until it restarts itself.

I recently had the same issue.  Except I was actually using 1507.  In my case, the installation was actually a virtual machine.  In my case, the installation was an Insider Preview build based on my notes, that was later upgraded to the final build (RTM) 10240 at some point.

I decided that it was time to update this machine, I spent the better part of a day attempting various methods to upgrade it one of the more recent Windows 10 versions, but each time I would receive an error.

[image]

This error message was only being displayed when I attempted to either use the current Upgrade Assistant and/or the Media Creation Tool.  When Windows Update attempted to install the feature update it would fail silently.  The machine would go through the process, reboot several times, and then suddenly start to roll the changes back.  So unless you watched the entire process you would miss what was happening (which is exactly what I was not doing).

> Please, help.. is there anything I am missing here, or there is something else that I need to. I want to update my windows to the latest version.

The only way I have found to upgrade older Windows 10 installations that are NOT on a build that is currently supported (1507,1511,1607,1703,1709) is to upgrade to each of those versions before attempting to upgrade to (1803,1809, and 1903).  Feature updates are only supported for 18 months, I have found any installation on an unsupported build, actually has problems getting updates.  This can be mitigated by keeping the system current with updates (security updates are released for all versions), but the Windows Catalog, does not archive updates forever.  It appears updates have a limited lifespan around 18 months, so updates for 1507 could not be downloaded, as they had already been removed.

I suspect I was receiving the error for several reasons.  The entire feature updates upgrade process has received improvements in the last 12 months.  So I suspecting attempting to upgrade from 1507 and/or 1511 to one of the builds after that improvement is not supported.

It also based on the fact the tools that can diagnose the upgrade process itself is likely also untested on systems upgraded from older feature updates to newer updates.  I used [SetupDiag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag) to diagnose the issue.  The documentation on the error codes appear to have been updated, I suspect the tool only supports updates after the upgrade improvements, because while the tool did parse the reason for the failure the documentation for the error did not seem to properly explain the failure.

I had to upgrade the machine to 1511, 1607, and finally 1703 before it successfully upgraded itself to 1803.  After it upgraded itself to 1703 (from 1603) it installed 1703 patches from 2018 automatically.  At this time it has not attempted to install any of patches released in the last 7 months for 1703.

In my original attempts I attempted to use WSUS Offline, but that tool downloads catalog files and depending on how long you went without updates it, the updates might have been already removed from the catalog.  Additionally, it appears WSUS Offline, only supports the supported feature updates (1803, 1809, 1903).  It appears WSUS Offline will only ever support upgrading the feature updates that exist within the SAC (Semi-Annual Channel).

Sources:

- [Windows 10 release information](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/)
- [Windows Update for Business and the retirement of SAC-T](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-IT-Pro-Blog/Windows-Update-for-Business-and-the-retirement-of-SAC-T/ba-p/339523)

Answer (score -1):

look at
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10/release-information

Version from 1607 to 1809
i think you must download ISO file and upgrade it and take care to **link** Microsoft account by your activation

Comment: Linking your Microsoft Account to your local profile isn’t actually required to activate Windows 10

Answer (score -2):

You need a fresh update then
 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO
Download and you will be at may 2019 copy fresh then it should install updates to nov 2019 fresh new build with your files still saved. I had same problem til this was downloaded. You just have an old copy of Windows. It helped our not updating problems as well.

Comment: Speaking from personal experience I can confirm this answer was not applicable to the author.  The upgrade would have failed, when I attempted an upgrade from 1507 to directly to 1803 the upgrade failed.  Due to the age the diagnostic tools made available by Microsoft misdiagnosed the error.