# Windows 10 rebooting in a loop to install updates -but already updated to 1903

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

hopefully someone can help.
I had a client whose HP laptop - tried to install 1803 update and failed into a reboot loop - troubleshoot - system restore enables access to the desktop. 
I downloaded 1903 media creator and brought the laptop uptodate. All seemed ok on restart and left the laptop with the client.
Now the laptop has gone back into a "installing update" loop even though it has 1903 update (successful so earlier updates not needed?) - 
Question is why windows can't figure out it is uptodate and where in the reboot process is it being told to try and install an update not needed? I need to break this loop - any ideas?
Thanks Andy

Comment: Wiping the system partition doesn’t do anything other than clear the BCD and destroying the bootloader. You would have to restore using Windows installation media and the problem would still persist. A full backup of all data that must be kept and a fully clean reinstallation of Windows is advised.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 is the machine running?  Please edit your question to include this vital required information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Windows 10 version 1511 won't update to latest 1803?](https://superuser.com/questions/1408021/my-windows-10-version-1511-wont-update-to-latest-1803)

Comment: The old system was 1803 on a Windows 10 Home HP laptop. It started to loop an update on reboot that failed and entered the diagnostic boot - using restore it was possible to get into windows. I updated to 1903 successfully - but a feature update is trying to keep installing - I want to be able to stop this as the laptop is already at 1903.... I have not touched the BCD as this is not needed to solve the issue. I just need to stop the reboot attempt to install an update that is NOT needed....

Answer (score 0):

update: the problem was linked to w/r fails on the HDD - consequently it failed to a RAW state - completely losing the partition. Customer had good backups so only took a few hours to rebuild... installed 1809 update and all looks good.