# How to get the Windows 10 1809 and not 1903?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1809

I am on an earlier Windows 10 version and would like to update to 1809, but not the new 1903.

I cannot find an official link to an update file. The Windows Update center, etc. only offers 1903.

How can I update to version 1809 manually? Thanks.

Comment: What version are you on exactly?

Comment: Windows 10 1607

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I update to version 1809 manually?

You will need to download the [Windows 10 version 1809 ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10).  Once you have downloaded the ISO, use the built-in capability to mount the ISO, and launch Setup.exe contained on the disk.

The installation process will proceed.  You will be prompted to update the installer, you will want to select the option that avoids this, otherwise, it will attempt to install the incorrect feature update.  An alternative to mounting the ISO within Windows is to create an installation disk and launch the Setup.exe from within Windows 10.

The installation of the feature upgrade **must** be done from within Windows 10, if you want to do an in-place upgrade, booting to the installation environment will result in a clean install of Windows 10.

> I am currently using Windows 10 1607.

You won't be able to upgrade from 1607 directly to 1809 or 1903.  You will have to first upgrade to 1703, then 1709, and finally to 1809.  You will need to use the method I explained above to upgrade to each version.  Since you will be installing multiple versions, and you won't be able to rollback, you should use the Disk Cleanup after each upgrade and remove the previous installation.

if you attempt to upgrade to 1809 or 1903 the upgrade likely will fail and will rollback.  [You will receive a generic SAFE_OS error](https://superuser.com/questions/1408021/my-windows-10-version-1511-wont-update-to-latest-1803/1443766#1443766)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info! What if I use the tool to upgrade to 1903 via the tool? Will that work?

Comment: @Niclas - You might want to read what I have written again.  You can't upgrade directly to 1809 or 1903.  You will have to do what I have said, at the bottom of my answer, it is indeed possible to upgrade to 1809 given your current configuration.  **You absolutely can upgrade to 1809, you might have to perform multiple upgrades, but you will end up having 1809 installed.**  I happen to actually be using Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 1607, you should edit your question to indicate that is the case, and not accept my answer.  **My answer only applies to consumer editions of Windows 10.**

Comment: Alright, thanks @Ramhound. I will try to upgrade to 1703, 1709, and then 1809. Is this website legit https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php ?

Comment: I linked to a question, with multiple ways, to get the ISOs for those versions.  I won't speak to the legitimacy of any specific website.  **If there is an answer with multiple upvotes. with a link to a website, you can assume it has been vetted by the community.**  I won't tell you how to get the ISO, that is entirely up to you, I am only telling you how to upgrade to 1809.

Comment: Do I need 1803 after 1709 to get to 1809? Thanks