# How to upgrade to a specific build of windows 10

Tags: windows, updates, dism

So, I have a Windows 10 installation that has all kinds of issues.

It's running Windows 10 Enterprise, 10.0.17134.1130 (x64)

I'm trying to restore this with DISM, using another installation of windows 10 as the source image, however, I'm having trouble getting this new installation to the correct version.

Currently, it is on: 10.0.10240, but when I try to run the MSU file `windows10.0-kb4525237-x64_dc82c2b90ed23d496f5f17acbb1dc5698634ac80.msu` I get a prompt saying this update isn't supported on my computer ...

Running windows update will put me on an update that is way too high for me to be able to run DISM.

Any ideas?

[Edit]

Rephrase ..

I have a windows 10 installation that is corrupt. This installation is windows 10 Enterprise, 10.0.17134.1130. This installation was once upon a time created using this ISO: SW_DVD5_WIN_ENT_10_64BIT_English_MLF_X20-26061.ISO

I now have a second installation of Windows 10 Enterprise, using the same ISO. However, before I run windows update, the build is 10.0.10240.

I need to get this second installation up to a version that matches my corrupt installation, in order to run DISM. However, whenever I run Windows Updates, it puts me at a build higher than desired.

Comment: I apologize if there was any confusion, I'm been pulling my hair out with this issue for 2 days now.

Comment: I have submitted an answer.  I suspect you will have problems using a second installation as a source for a working Windows Component Store (WinSxS). However, if you download the proper ISO yourself, you will be able to upgrade to `Windows 10 version 1803` instead of `Windows 10 version 1903` being offered through Windows Update.  If you want help with the specific issue with the problem installation, that would be a different question, and specific enough on the problems would be required.  *How you use an ISO as a source for DISM is beyond the scope of my answer.*

Comment: I appreciate the breakdown, this greatly clarifies things for me! I’ll go over this in the evening when I have a chance to. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to restore this with DISM, using another installation of
>   windows 10 as the source image, however, I'm having trouble getting
>   this new installation to the correct version.

You obviously cannot use a Windows 10 version 1507 installation to repair a Windows 10 version 1803 installation.  This means you must manually update Windows 10 version 1507 to Windows 10 version 1803.

> I now have a second installation of Windows 10 Enterprise, using the same ISO. However, before I run windows update, the build is 10.0.10240.  I need to get this second installation up to a version that matches my corrupt installation, in order to run DISM. However, whenever I run Windows Updates, it puts me at a build higher than desired.

This is due to the fact that `Windows 10 version 1803` is currently is not supported.  The reason you are being offered `Windows 10 version 1903` is due to the fact that it is the currently supported version of Windows 10.  This means you must download a `Windows 10 version 1803` ISO and manually update the `Windows 10 version 1507` installation.

You can use [this](https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/67-microsoft-windows-and-office-iso-download-tool?showall=&limitstart=) tool to download the `Windows 10 Enterprise version 1803` ISO.  If you do not trust the tool then you can download the required ISO from the [Licensing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx).

Source: [Where can I get a clean ISO of a specific build of Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10)

However, you might run into issues, trying to upgrade 1507 directly to 1803.  **If that happens you will have to incrementally upgrade to each version.**  If you run into problems, you will want to avoid allowing the installation environment (from within Windows) to download updates since that will not give you the end result you want.  I actually documented that entire process, and the problems I ran into, in a previous answer to a different question.

You could avoid the issues trying to upgrade the second installation by simply installing `Windows 10 version 1803` on the system using the ISO you download.  You can also use that same ISO, on the problem machine, and use it to repair the installation.

Source: [My Windows 10 version 1511 won't update to latest 1803?](https://superuser.com/questions/1408021/my-windows-10-version-1511-wont-update-to-latest-1803/1443766#1443766)

> when I try to run the MSU file windows10.0-kb4525237-x64_dc82c2b90ed23d496f5f17acbb1dc5698634ac80.msu I get a prompt saying this update isn't supported on my computer

[KB4525237](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb4525237) can only be installed on `Windows 10 version 1803`.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, this makes much better sense now, and I've successfully rebuilt my OS. Thanks!