# Does an update require the last version to be accomplished?

Tags: windows-7, updates

I don't mean an update of particular software on a particular platform. Of course, then the answer is "depend" but how? My doubt arises when updating Windows 10 (wait, not for me): when all updates were installed, I rebooted the system but new updates were available. At that point I was wondering why Windows update center didn't find all the updates at once. If you want to see in another way: if now I turn on a, say, 2016 smartphone, would be this capable of update Whatsapp to the last version all at once?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1408021/my-windows-10-version-1511-wont-update-to-latest-1803/1443766#1443766) probably doesn’t directly answer your question but it might.  Questions about mobile phones are specifically out of scope

Comment: I understood the question to be more about how updates work and that is in scope. The mobile portion  I saw as an example. Question is fine in my view.

Comment: Not all software updates the same way. Some updates are cumulative. Others aren’t. Why? Who knows. It depends on the manufacturer and their needs and processes.

Comment: Yes and I addressed that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> when all updates were installed, I rebooted the system but new updates
> were available. At that point I was wondering why Windows update
> center didn't find all the updates at once.

Windows occasionally has to restart to get the next batch of updates. Not all the time, not even most of the time, but sometimes.

Windows 10 can go from zero (new install with the Vendor's USB key) to up to date in about two update sessions, one after the other. I did this installing a new drive. V10240 to V1511 then to V1809 in one step. V1809 was current at the time.

> I turn on a, say, 2016 smartphone, would be this capable of update
> Whatsapp to the last version all at once

My iPhone generally updates to the newest version from wherever it started. If I update IOS, I typically find new updates again (similar to what I said in Windows above).

My own Windows apps (many of them) will generally update through two or three versions. Again there are exceptions - far fewer than more.

So in general, you do not have to update to the last version before updating to the next version. Software vendors will normally be explicit if you must update in some sequence.