# Update Windows 10 without internet

Tags: windows-10, updates

How can I update my Windows 10 Home computer? I just installed it and it has versión 1709

Paint dot net requires version 1809

I don't have internet, is there any service pack I can download on a USB drive?

Comment: If you google "update windows 10 without internet" you'll get hundreds of results with written instructions, procedures, videos, and even apps to help  you

Comment: "is there any service pack I can download on a USB drive?" - Windows 10 does not have Service Packs. The installation of a feature pack, requires Windows to be upgrade, which involves reinstalling the new version and transfering the user data to the new installation. What stage of that process are you having problems performing exactly? [You might find it difficult to perform the upgrade.](https://superuser.com/questions/1408021/my-windows-10-version-1511-wont-update-to-latest-1803/1443766#1443766)

Comment: how did you post this question ...

Comment: @JaromandaX - I have internet on my smartphone and I have limited traffic - about 10 GB / month, so I can't connect my computer using the phone as a hotspot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

You will need to
[Download Official Windows 10 ISO file from Microsoft](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/9230-download-windows-10-iso-file.html)
and then
[Create Bootable USB Flash Drive to Install Windows 10 from](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html).

Installing the upgrade without requiring a boot media is by
opening the ISO in Windows and running the `setup.exe` program.

Comment: Technically, if the author uses a 22H2 ISO, they would be upgrading to 22H2, and not actually performing an in-place upgrade. In-place upgrade typically refers to reinstall the same version, that is currently being used, in order to repair the system integrity.

Comment: @Ramhound - I bought Windows 10 Home in 2018 and it was 1709 so now I got 5 years worth of updates, this answer worked very well for me, which is great!

Comment: @JoeJobs - I have made the same suggestion in the past.